# How to grep for some specific parts, from a file?

Tags: text, grep, set

I need to extract some specifiek parts from a 'very big > 3GB' text file.

> ```
> ,(1,'test@hotmail.com',0,0,1,1,0,0,1),
>  (2,'test4@hotmail.com',1,0,3,1,7,0,1),
>  (3,'test2@live.com',0,0,0,1,0,0,1),
>  (4,'test5@hotmail.com',1,0,7,1,1,1,3),
>  (5,'test3@hotmail.com',0,0,3,1,1,0,1),
>  (6,'test6@hotmail.com',1,0,5,1,6,1,1),
> ```

And I need 'first field, email, third field' so (without the `''`) and by line as below..

> ```
> 1,test@hotmail.com,0
>
> 2,test4@hotmail.com,1
>
> 3,test2@live.com,0
> ```
>
> etc..

And if possible I want extract the domain names (like 1,test@hotmail.com,hotmail.com,0 )

I can extract the emails with the following:

```
grep -o -E '\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b' test
```

and I tried a lot more... 
like `egrep -o -E '([^),(^]+)' test`, and `set`

I hope someone get help me out!

Comment: If every line has the same columns, try `AWK`.

Comment: I tried AWK already, I got only first line `(1,'test@hotmail.com',0` with `awk -F "," 'BEGIN{OFS=",";} {print $2,$3,$4;}' test`

Comment: You mean all of this in one line?

Comment: Yes, `awk -F "," 'BEGIN{OFS=",";} {print $2,$3,$4;}' test` test is the text file (small part)

Comment: How about this `tr ")('" "\n  "   < file | awk -F"," '{print $2","$3","$4}'`

Comment: Thanks! this print all the lines, but at the begin of all lines there is a space and at the end two comma's on a new line ` 1,test@hotmail.com,0`, I add sed to remove the '' with `tr ')(' '\n ' < test | sed "s/'//g" | awk -F"," '{print $2","$3","$4}'` but we are almost there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `tr` to split the very long line to multi lines.

Then use `tr` to remove the special chars like `()`.

Finally, use `AWK` to print output the expected columns.

`tr ")('" "\n  "   < file | tr -d "[ ]" |awk -F"," '{print $2","$3","$4}'`

---

**UPDATE**

Then just `split` the email or hostname would solve your problem.

`tr ")" "\n"   < file | tr -d "[ (']" |awk -F"," '{ split($3, a, "@"); print $2","$3","a[2]","$4;}'`

---

**FINAL UPDATE**

Add a check, only print the legal lines.

`tr ")" "\n"   < file | tr -d "[ (']" |awk -F"," '{ split($3, a, "@"); if (NF>2) {print $2","$3","a[2]","$4;}}'`

**OUTPUT**

```
1,t@hotmail.com,hotmail.com,0
2,test4@hotmail.com,hotmail.com,1
3,test2@live.com,live.com,0
```

Comment: This remove the space, but not the `,,` on the end (one time). And how can i  make a new field for the domain names? so like `1,test@hotmail.com,hotmail.com,0`

Comment: I don't understand `make a new field for the domain names`, give sample data maybe? It's another question maybe.

Comment: like `tr ")('" "\n  "   < test | tr -d "[ ]" |awk -F"," '{print $2","$3","$3","$4}'`, but then remove the first part from the second "$3" (@)

Comment: Updated the answer.  It's fells like you are asking question after question when I solved one then another. Updating question over and over would take too much time to answer one question, which was not very good.

Comment: Well, update for the last time. That shoud work, and there shouldn't be any new question bro.